# Code analyzer capable to detect resource leak

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, static-analysis, findbugs

May I know if there is any free code analyzer that can find out the "Improper resource shutdown or release of IO or Database resources". I have tried findbugs and Sonar. Both were able to identify only those that are not closed. It couldn't identify the improperly closed ones.

ex: Sonar and Find bugs was unable to detect code like this:

```
void method() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader();
    String str = br.readLine();
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: Which version of SonarQube and its sonar java analyzer did you used ? the latest version of the java analyzer should be able to detect such cases.

Comment: Sonarqube 5.6.There is a rule called "Resources should be closed" in it which is supposed to identify this case as per the rule description .But it is not able to identify. It is only reporting those that are not closed.

Comment: Here is the [rule](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2095) mentioned. You need to check if it has been disabled in your rules. It's default level of severity is Blocker so it should be enabed by default.

Comment: It is enabled.It is the only rule that I have added to my quality profile and is activated.But it is only reporting the unclosed ones.There is a case where the resources were closed in the try block but was not reported.

Comment: What is the version of the sonar java analyzer you are using ?

Comment: It is Sonarqube 5.6

Comment: One more question on this.When configuring a project with Sonar , the process I was going through was  : adding the project to Sonar and then building it after which Sonar is reporting the bugs for the particular quality profile.May I know if this is the right process or do we need to run the project .I mean does sonar check the code in runtime for any bugs.(in my case the improper resource shutdown.